# SQL Server: Query SysProcesses and InputBuffer

Tags: sql-server-2008, with-statement, input-buffer

I am trying to pull the input buffer data (`DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@SPID)`) for each record returned for a database when querying the `SYSPROCESSES` table. I am interested to hear if there is a better way to accomplish this, but would also appreciate correction to what I currently have working for learning purposes.

```
DECLARE @Max [int]
DECLARE @Min [int] = 1

SELECT @Max = COUNT(SPID)
FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES
WHERE DB_NAME(DBID) = 'Northwinds' AND DBID != 0

CREATE TABLE #Results (
    EventType [nvarchar](1024),
    Parameters [int],
    EventInfo [nvarchar](1024),
    SPID [int],
    STATUS [nvarchar](255),
    PROGRAM_NAME [nvarchar](1024),
    CMD [nvarchar](255),
    LOGINAME [nvarchar](255)
)

WHILE @Min <= @Max
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SPID [int]

    WITH SelectedRow AS (
        SELECT SPID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SPID) AS RowNumber
        FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES
        WHERE DB_NAME(DBID) = 'Northwinds' AND DBID != 0
    )

    SELECT @SPID = SPID
    FROM SelectedRow
    WHERE RowNumber = @Min

    DECLARE @InputBuffer TABLE (
        EventType [nvarchar](1024),
        Parameter [int],
        EventInfo [nvarchar](1024)
    )

    DECLARE @SysProcesses TABLE (
        SPID [int],
        STATUS [nvarchar](255),
        PROGRAM_NAME [nvarchar](1024),
        CMD [nvarchar](255),
        LOGINAME [nvarchar](255)
    )

    INSERT @InputBuffer 
        EXEC('DBCC INPUTBUFFER('+@SPID+')')

    INSERT @SysProcesses 
        SELECT SPID, STATUS, PROGRAM_NAME, CMD, LOGINAME
        FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES
        WHERE DB_NAME(DBID) = 'Northwinds' AND DBID != 0 AND SPID = @SPID

    INSERT INTO #TempResults(EventType, Parameters, EventInfo, SPID, STATUS, PROGRAM_NAME, CMD, LOGINAME)
        SELECT *
        FROM @InputBuffer, @SysProcesses

    SET @Min = (@Min + 1)
END
```

Now when I execute the following query:

```
SELECT SPID
FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES
WHERE DB_NAME(DBID) = 'Northwinds' AND DBID != 0
```

it returns 31 rows...

However when I `SELECT * FROM #TempResults` after executing the above loop I am returning mass amounts of duplicates in the temp table...to the sum of 10751.

Again this is mostly for learning, but would be a pretty handy function to have as well. I am looking for information on what I'm missing causing the duplicate records to be returned, as well as a possible better solution.

Comment: Please, go get sp_whoIsActive and save yourself this headache.  https://sqlblog.org/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/27/who-is-active-v11-00-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-27-of-30.aspx

Comment: @Aaron, Thank you, that will come in extremely useful. I am also trying to expand my SQL knowledge so I would still like assistance on why the loop is returning so many records. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
INSERT #Results
SELECT * 
FROM @InputBuffer, @SysProcesses
```

This is effectively a cross join, so if either table has more than one row, you're going to have `COUNT(left side) * COUNT(right side)` rows as a result. Maybe you should use `SELECT DISTINCT column list` instead or, as I suggested in my comment, stop looping through `sysprocesses` (deprecated) and retrieving info from `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` - even for educational purposes that is painful.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below query for better result

```
DEclare @SPID [int]
DEclare @database_name [nvarchar](1024)
DEclare @hostname [nvarchar](1024)
DEclare @PROGRAM_NAME [nvarchar](1024)
DEclare @LOGINNAME [nvarchar](255)
DEclare @Inputbuffer [nvarchar] (4000)

CREATE TABLE #TempResults (
  SPID [int],
  database_name [nvarchar](1024),
  hostname [nvarchar](1024),
  PROGRAM_NAME [nvarchar](1024),
  LOGINAME [nvarchar](255),
  EventType [nvarchar](1024),
  Parameters [int],
  EventInfo [nvarchar](4000)
)


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select spid,db_name(dbid), hostname,program_name,loginame from sys.sysprocesses where dbid in(11,10,13,14,15,16)  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @spid,@database_name,@hostname,@program_name,@loginname   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

     create table #InputBuffer1  (
    EventType [nvarchar](1024),
    Parameter [int],
    EventInfo [nvarchar](4000)
)

    INSERT into #InputBuffer1 
    EXEC('DBCC INPUTBUFFER('+@SPID+')')

create TABLE #SysProcesses  (
    SPID [int],
database_name [nvarchar](1024),
hostname [nvarchar](1024),
PROGRAM_NAME [nvarchar](1024),
LOGINAME [nvarchar](255)
)



INSERT INTO #SysProcesses(spid,database_name,hostname,program_name,LOGINAME) 
    SELECT  @spid,@database_name,@hostname,@program_name,@loginname

     insert into #TempResults
     select * from #SysProcesses,#InputBuffer1

    drop table #InputBuffer1
    drop table #SysProcesses


   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @spid,@database_name,@hostname,@program_name,@loginname  
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

select *  from #TempResults
```

Answer (score 0):

May be is later, but for anyone interested, **MASTER.DBO.sysprocesses** returns a row for each parel procees and **sys.sysprocesses** only the parent process.